# Updating data members of different derived classes of the same base class within a vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I am writing a 3D gridded model in C++ which has different cell types, all stored within a vector that is in a *Grid* class. I have defined a base *GridCell* class and I also have two derived classes *GridCell1* and *GridCell2*.

Now in setting up the model, I read in a text file that tells me how to fill my *gridCell* vector `(std::vector<gridCell*> gridCellVector)` in the *Grid* class; meaning it tells me what types of derived cells to push_back into my *gridCellVector*.

Then I read in another input file that contains initial state variable information for each *GridCell* in my *Grid*, in the order laid out by the 1st input file.

Each derived class (*GridCell1* and *GridCell2*) has some state variables (private data members) that the other doesn't.  How can I (or is it possible to) access and update/initialize/set the derived class' data members as I read in the second input file?

I've tried a couple different things and seem only able to return my get/set functions defined in the *GridCell* base class.  I can't figure out how to access the functions in the derived classes when working with each derived *GridCell* as I step through the vector.

**Edit:**  I am surprised people haven't mentioned downcasting, other than saying not to use dynamic_cast.  I always know the type of *GridCell* I am updating because I keep track of what has been loaded into the vector when reading in the first input file.  Since i am always certain of the type of *GridCell*, isn't dynamic_cast safe?

**Double Edit:**. Because I pass the *GridCell* objects to other functions that need to reference the data members and functions specific to the appropriate *GridCell* instance of the passed object, I'm realizing the design (of many parts) of my model does not currently pass muster.  So, for now, I'm giving up on the idea of having to ride the *GridCell*types at all and will just create one huge *GridCell* class that fits all my needs.  This way I can fill, and then access, whatever data members and functions I need later on down the line.

Comment: Could you scan both files at once?

Comment: I could, but then some of my setup functions will become unwieldy and too large.  It may be hard to break them down....Is there no way to do it in a two step process?

Comment: Too large and unwieldy? I think it will actually give you the simplest, most elegant code. You can do it in a two-step process if you really want to (e.g. with `dynamic_cast`) but I don't advise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you want to use a two-step process, I suggest you give `GridCell` a pure virtual `init` method:

```
virtual void init(istream &) = 0;
```

then implement it in each derived class. Its purpose is to read data from the file and initialize the initial state variables.

Comment: I'd go a step further and make this a `virtual void` method, so the derived class gets the data and can do what it needs, and then he can do `gridCell::init`, and the base class gets the data as well in case it needs it.

Comment: @NicFoster: Yeah, I said "virtual" in the text, and making it virtual is really the whole point, and yet I left it out of the code. It's been a long day. Editing...

Comment: It doesn't feel like initializing from an `ifstream` should really be the responsibility of a `GridCell`. It is not very testable for one thing. Also, everytime you make a change to your file format you have to change `GridCell`. At least make it take an `istream` instead of a `ifstream` so it is slightly more testable.

Comment: This is a pretty terrible plan really.

Comment: @Puppy: If you know of one that's much better, given the OP's preference for a two-stage solution, please enlighten us.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Initializing from a stream must be *something's* responsibility, and when you change the file format you must change that code, wherever it is; I don't see much value in introducing a lot of new code just to formally (and only formally) separate this functionality from the `GridCell` family. As for `istream`/`ifstream`, you're right, `istream` is better; I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

### Single pass

As others have said, it may be best to read both files at once and do the derived class specific initialization at the same time as creating the derived classes:

```
std::unique_ptr<GridCell> createGridCell1(std::istream& init) {
    auto cell = std::make_unique<GridCell1>();
    int value; 
    init >> value;
    cell->setGridCell1State(value);   
    return cell;
}

std::unique_ptr<GridCell> createGridCell2(std::istream& init) {
    // similarly to CreateGridCell1()...
}

std::vector<GridCell::Ptr> createCells(std::istream& types, std::istream& init) {
    std::vector<GridCell::Ptr> cells;
    std::string type;
    while (types >> type) {
        if (type == "GridCell1")
            cells.push_back(createGridCell1(init));
        else
            cells.push_back(createGridCell2(init));
    }
    return cells;
}

int main() {
    auto types = std::istringstream("GridCell1 GridCell2 GridCell1 GridCell1");
    auto init = std::istringstream("1 2.4 2 3");

    auto cells = createCells(types, init);

    for (auto& cell : cells) 
        cell->put();
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wME2yg8JWh6hpY7A).

### Two pass with Visitor

If you *must* do the initialization in a second pass you could use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). You have some sort of `GridCellVisitor` that knows how to visit all the different kinds of grid cells:

```
class GridCellVisitor {
protected:
    ~GridCellVisitor() = default;
public:
    virtual void visit(GridCell1& cell) = 0;
    virtual void visit(GridCell2& cell) = 0;
};
```

and your grid cells know how to accept a `GridCellVisitor`:

```
class GridCell1 : public GridCell {
    int state = 0;
public:
    void setGridCell1State(int value) { state = value; }
    void accept(GridCellVisitor& visitor) override { visitor.visit(*this); }
};

class GridCell2 : public GridCell {
    double state = 0.0;
public:
    void setGridCell2State(double value) { state = value; }
    void accept(GridCellVisitor& visitor) override { visitor.visit(*this); }
};
```

This way you can separate the responsibility of initializing the grid cells with an input stream from the grid cells themselves and avoid having to do fragile downcasts on the grid cells:

```
class GridCellStreamInitializer : public GridCellVisitor {
    std::istream* in;
public:
    GridCellStreamInitializer(std::istream& in) : in(&in){}
    void visit(GridCell1& cell) override { 
        int value; 
        *in >> value;
        cell.setGridCell1State(value);
    }

    void visit(GridCell2& cell) override {
        double value;
        *in >> value;
        cell.setGridCell2State(value);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto in = std::istringstream("GridCell1 GridCell2 GridCell1 GridCell1");
    auto cells = createCells(in);

    auto init = std::istringstream("1 2.4 2 3");
    auto streamInitializer = GridCellStreamInitializer(init);
    for (auto& cell : cells)
        cell->accept(streamInitializer);
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JCcdUjH6Gs3P4B4P).

The downside is `GridCellVisitor` must be aware of all different kinds of grid cells so if you add a new type of grid cell you have to update the visitor. But as I understand it your code that reads the initialization file must be aware of all the different kinds of grid cells anyway.

Comment: This seems OK except for the part where all of the detail and code in the answer shows the second, terrible solution, instead of the first solution.

Comment: @Puppy I've added some example code for the first solution but if the requirement is that it _must_ be done in two passes I actually think the Visitor pattern is a reasonable fit.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vector<gridCell*>` knows only the base class of its elements and can hence only call `gridCell` functions.

I understand that your approach, is to first fill the vector with pointer to cells of the correct derived type, and never the base type.  Then for each cell, you read class dependent data.

## The easiest way, if you don't want to change approach

The cleanest way would be to define a virtual load function in the base cell:

```
class gridCell {
   ...
   virtual bool load (ifstream &ifs) {
       // load the common data of all gridCells and derivates
       return ifs.good();  
   } 
};
```

The virtual function would be overriden by teh derived cells:

```
class gridCell1 : public gridCell {
   ...
   bool load (ifstream &ifs) override {
       if (gridCell::load(ifs)) {  // first load the common part
          // load the derivate specific data 
       }
       return ifs.good();  
   } 
};
```

Finally, you can write your container loading function:

```
class Grid {
    ... 
    bool load (ifstream &ifs) {
        for (auto x:gridCellVector) 
            if (!x->load(ifs))
               break;  // error ? premature end of file ? ... 
    } 
 };
```

## The cleanest way ?

Your problem looks very much like a serialisation problem.  You load grids, may be you write grids as well ? If you control the file format, and perform the creation and loading of the cells in a single pass,  then you don't need to reinvent the wheel and could opt for a serialisation library,  like **[`boost::serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)**.