# What's wrong with using dynamic_cast or static_cast when accessing known derived class objects stored in vector<base*>?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, dynamic-cast, static-cast

This is a follow-up to my question here: 
[Updating data members of different derived classes of the same base class within a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31911663/1762492)

I am building a 3D gridded model in C++ which has different cell types, all stored within a vector that is in a *Grid* class. I have defined a base *GridCell* class and I also have several derived classes *GridCell1*, *GridCell2*, *GridCell3*, and so on.

Into the model processes I pass a *GridCell* object.  The *GridCell* object type (which derived class) that is passed will work with the receiving model processes.  In other words, the model processes The model processes were designed (possibly incorrectly) with different functions expecting to act the on appropriate derived objects' data members. Which, of course, they can't see because the the object is pulled from the `std::vector<gridCell*> gridCellVector` so it only sees the object as a pointer to the base class.  At this point, I have two options:  1) Rewrite my model processes, 2) use static_cast or dynamic_cast to downcast the passed object.

**Question:** In this scenario, when my model processes (which are only run on the right type of *GridCell* object) know what derived class they are receiving, should I use static_cast or dynamic_cast? People seem to really frown on the use of these tools. Why should I stay away from using these?

Comment: It is not that `dynamic_cast` should not be used. It's that you should use it only when you've exhausted the possibility of solving your problem using virtual functions.

Comment: I wish I could mark both of the answers as correct, because they both teach and show me different things.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes casting is inevitable because polymorphism does not solve every problem. However polymorphism was actually designed to remove the need to *know the type*. If you need to know the type then you have to ask if polymorphism is the right tool for the job, or else if you have failed to implement polymorphism correctly.

The *ideal* is that each object knows its own behaviour so that no one else needs to make `if/else` decisions when dealing with the *general* type.

To that effect you would normally put the processing code inside the type itself rather than have external processing routines that need to make `if/else` decisions for each object they receive.

So whereas casting is not *inherently* bad because *sometimes* it is necessary, it is also *potentially* a symptom of poor design if you need to use it.

> **Question:** In this scenario, when my model processes (which are only run on the right type of *GridCell* object) know what derived
>   class they are receiving, should I use static_cast or dynamic_cast?
>   People seem to really frown on the use of these tools. Why should I
>   stay away from using these?

If you *really* know the type then use `static_cast` (its faster) otherwise use `dynamic_cast`.

**An alternative to casting:**

One "trick" you can use, which effectively is casting, is to use *polymorphism* to select the correct type for you.

What you can do is add a *virtual function* to your base class `GridCell` that takes the *object* of the class that is processing the subtypes separately and get the overriding subtypes to call the relevant processing function themselves. This way the *type* inherently *knows* how it needs to be processed.

**An example**

```
class Processor
{
public:

    void process_1(class GridCell1* cell)
    {
        std::cout << "processing type 1\n";
    }

    void process_2(class GridCell2* cell)
    {
        std::cout << "processing type 2\n";
    }
};

class GridCell
{
public:
    virtual ~GridCell() {}

    virtual void process(Processor& proc) = 0;
};

class GridCell1
: public GridCell
{
public:
    void process(Processor& proc) override
    {
        proc.process_1(this);
    }
};

class GridCell2
: public GridCell
{
public:
    void process(Processor& proc) override
    {
        proc.process_2(this);
    }
};

class Grid
{
    std::vector<GridCell*> gridCellVector;

public:
    Grid()
    {
        gridCellVector.push_back(new GridCell1);
        gridCellVector.push_back(new GridCell1);
        gridCellVector.push_back(new GridCell2);
        gridCellVector.push_back(new GridCell1);
        gridCellVector.push_back(new GridCell2);
        gridCellVector.push_back(new GridCell1);
    }

    ~Grid() { for(auto cell: gridCellVector) delete cell; }

    void process()
    {
        Processor proc;
        for(auto cell: gridCellVector)
            cell->process(proc);
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Grid grid;

    grid.process();
}
```

**Output:**

```
processing type 1
processing type 1
processing type 2
processing type 1
processing type 2
processing type 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using static_cast<> in the described situation is unsafe, since the described cast is a downcast to an unknown derived class, and the most fitting explanation to why not use a static_cast is:

> If new_type is a pointer or reference to some class D and the type of expression is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base B, static_cast performs a downcast. Such static_cast makes no runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D, and may only be used safely if this precondition is guaranteed by other means, such as when implementing static polymorphism. Safe downcast may be done with dynamic_cast.
>   [(Read more about static_cast conversion)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

If the different objects (gridCell1, gridCell2) have different and new functions, say f1() and f2(), that doesn't appear in the base class as a virtual function - it's not possible to use the polymorphic mechanism of c++, since the compiler only sees the base object function during compilation time and cannot access functions of derived classes.

However, you could add a mechanism to help you determine an object type during runtime using RTTI. By making the base class abstract you will have a vtbl created for each derived class, and you can attempt a dynamic_cast to each one of the derived objects. If the cast fails it will return a null and you continue to try other derived classes until it succeeds, and than you can use the desired function.

Example:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void f() = 0;;  
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
    public:
    virtual void f() 
    {
        cout << "DerivedA::f()";    
    }
    void f1()
    {
        cout << "DerivedA::f1()";
    }
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
    public:
    virtual void f() 
    {
        cout << "DerivedB::f()";    
    }
    void f2()
    {
        cout << "DerivedB::f2()";
    }
};

void foo(Base* baseObj)
{
    DerivedA* a = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(baseObj);
    if (a)
    {
        a->f1();
        return;
    }
    DerivedB* b = dynamic_cast<DerivedB*>(baseObj);
    if (b)
    {
        b->f2();
        return;
    }
}

int main() {
    DerivedB* bObj = new DerivedB();
    foo(bObj); //will print DerivedB::f2()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Important notice: dynamic_cast is known to be slower during run-time, and might not be a good idea if its used occasionally in graphic algorithms.